# What unit of energy does PySCF use?

Tags: pyscf

The documentation for PySCF can be found here: https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/

However, it does not explicitly state in the documentation what unit of energy is used.
Is there a way to find this out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same as any other electronic structure code: [atomic units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree_atomic_units) are used. The unit of energy is Hartree, $E_h$, in which the ground state energy of hydrogen is exactly $-0.5$. One Hartree is roughly 27.211 386 245 988 eV, see [the NIST database](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?hrev). The atomic unit for length is the Bohr radius, $a_0$.

Defining things in terms of atomic units has the huge advantage that the results of a calculation don't depend on the numerical values of various conversion factors, e.g. Å to bohr in the input geometry conversion, and hartree to eV in the energy printout...

Comment: It should be noted that some codes (VASP) use electron volts.

Comment: Well yes, but in this case the output usually says eV. Atomic units are dimensionless, which makes them an optimal choice for computer implementations.

Comment: A good point :)